# redux form with material UI select component returning 'undefined' for fields onSubmit

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, redux-form

I am using material-ui selectField component within a redux-form field.  If the form is blank (creating a new hospital) it works perfectly. I can submit and save and all is well.  However, If I include initialValues (editing and existing hospital) they show up fine and I can edit the dropdown value, but when I SUBMIT the form , the values are undefined.

My Material-UI Component:

```
export class RenderSelectField extends Component { 
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: null,
    };
  }
  render() {
    const { initialValue, input, label, options, meta: { touched, error }, children } = this.props;
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme()}>
        <SelectField
          {...input}
          floatingLabelText={label}
          errorText={touched && error}
          onChange={(event, index, value) => input.onChange(value, this.setState({ value }))}
          children={children}
          maxHeight={400}
          autoWidth
          value={this.state.value || initialValue}         
        >
          {options.map((option) => <MenuItem value={option.id} key={option.id} primaryText={`${option.first} ${option.last}`} />)}
        </SelectField>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

My Redux form field:

```
<Field
  component={RenderSelectField}
  name="regional_director" 
  label="Regional director"
  options={this.props.contacts}
  initialValue={regional_director.id}
 />
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.